# Getting static web context resources to work on both bookmarkable and non-bookmarkable Wicket pages

Tags: css, tomcat, wicket, static-resource

In a Wicket 1.4 app, I have some static CSS & JS resources under `[project root]/WebContent/css` and `[project root]/WebContent/js` respectively.

[image]

My Wicket HTML files are in `src/resources/fi/company/product/pages` with corresponding Java classes in `src/main/fi/company/product/pages`. (In the resulting WAR file, the HTML & property files are of course in the same places as Java classes.)

The HTML files contain references to the resources such as:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar.js"></script>
</head>
```

This works fine everywhere (or so we thought until recently). NB: my Java code does not reference these resources at all.

Looking at the source of a rendered page (whose URL is e.g. `http://localhost:8080/report/42.4` or `http://localhost:8080/?wicket:interface=:6::::` ), the resource reference appears as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css"/>
```

However, we just noticed that **when the app is deployed somewhere else than (Tomcat) root**, the resources break on **non-bookmarkable pages**.

In other words, when the URL is e.g.

`http://localhost:8080/foobar/?wicket:interface=:2::::`

and a page refers to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css"/>
```

...the browser tries to fetch the resource at the invalid URL

```
http://localhost:8080/css/main.css
```

Now, **what is the simplest (yet non-hacky) way to get these static resources working**, regarless of the deployment path?

I could switch to using bookmarkable pages exclusively (which would require changing the constructors of the pages), but I suppose that shouldn't be necessary...

---

**Edit**: Looks like I got CSS resources working (on most places) simply by using `<wicket:link>`, [as advised in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182231/wicket-css-resources):

```
<head>
    <wicket:link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
    </wicket:link>
</head>
```

However, now the CSS references are broken on a page with an URL like `http://localhost:8080/foobar/report/42.9`

Wicket is trying to do something strange with the "css/main.css" path:

```
ERROR org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle - Can't instantiate page using constructor public fi.company.product.pages.ReportPage(org.apache.wicket.PageParameters) and argument 0 = "css" 1 = "main"
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor public fi.company.product.pages.ReportPage(org.apache.wicket.PageParameters) and argument 0 = "css" 1 = "main"
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:212)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:89)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:305)
```

**Edit 2**: Actually I'm not sure if `<wicket:link>` is the right solution here, since these resource files are **not** "[class path resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10186246/56285)". I guess my question is, **can you make this work while still using web context resources** (i.e., without making these class path resources)?

Comment: A curious thing is that without any changes, it seems I can no longer reproduce the problem... Now the CSS references are like `css/main.css` except on URLs like /foobar/report/42 where they are like `../css/main.css`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I solved it, and the solution turned out to be very surprising.

Earlier I wrote:

> A curious thing is that without any changes, it seems I can no longer
>   reproduce the problem...

That wasn't quite true, as I had made *one* small change (that I thought was inconsequential): I had deleted a file `WebContent/index.jsp` which in our project was a remnant that served no purpose.

Once it dawned on me that this could have fixed it, I did some more testing, and indeed:

For static resources to work as expected, **you must not have an `index.html` or `index.jsp` file in the root web content directory** (i.e., the parent of the CSS and JS resource dirs), as that in some cases breaks `../` references.

This probably isn't even Wicket-specific, but perhaps it is Tomcat-specific—if anyone knows more, feel free to chime in. I'm dubious whether this question ever helps anyone else, but still, glad I got it working!